# What is the value of this sum involving q-binomials?

Tags: co.combinatorics, qa.quantum-algebra, binomial-coefficients, enumerative-combinatorics, q-analogs

Let $n\ge 2r$ be positive integers.
Is there a closed form for following finite summation involving in q-binomial coefficients 
$$\sum_{s=0}^r(-1)^sq^{\frac{s(s+1)}{2}}{n-2r+s\brack n-2r}_q{n\brack r-s}_q\,\,\,\,\,\,   ?$$ 
I found this while studying q-Fibonacci/ Lucas polynomials.
What is the general approach for evaluating this type of series?
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your definition of $\big[..\big]_q$ ?

Comment: I use the definition $[n]_q=1+q+q^2+\cdots+q^{n-1}$ for q-integers .

Comment: Out of curiosity: where did you find this sum? I mean did you find it mentioned in some paper or is it a byproduct of some calculations of yours? It would be helpful to add some more context.

Comment: I an also very curious about the sum - it looks like the major index statistic on some family of lattice paths with some restriction (using inclusion-exclusion)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doron Zeilberger has written a Maple code for checking and proving [ordinary binomial identities](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/tokhniot/EKHAD) and their $q$-analogues. What you need in the present case is the package called [qEKHAD](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/tokhniot/qEKHAD).

I just tested your sum and it leads to a quadratic recurrence in $r$, so you may not expect a closed form as an answer. The lucky cases are linear recurrences in the "external" parameter (here, it is $r$). The latter situation fits the so-called [Wilf-Zeilberger pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilf%E2%80%93Zeilberger_pair).

I also sought for other factors $q^{\mu(s)}$ instead of $q^{\binom{s+1}2}$, none of the usual suspects lead to a closed form. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am tring to simplify this summation bit further. Numerical values suggest that above sum equal to $\sum_{s=0}^{r-1}(-1)^{s+1}q^{\frac{s(s+1)}{2}}{n-2r+s\brack n-2r}_q{n\brack r-s-1}_q.$ And also I fund that this equality holds for ordinary binomial coefficients (in which $q=1$). Do you think that they are actually equals for q-binomials?

Comment: I just checked: the two sums satisfy the same quadratic recurrence (in $n$) and matching initial conditions. They are indeed equal.

Comment: I found [this paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjlwfPVxdnRAhUP3WMKHWSMD7wQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.306.5080%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&usg=AFQjCNGHd03Dpi2TIErOk--MrQIbRUofMg) by Wilf and Zeilberger. Does the same algorithm works for q-analogies?

Comment: Yes, it does work the same way.